# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when trying to save XDocument in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

When I try to save my Xdocument in a XML file I have a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` exception, my XML file is already created.

My code:

```cs
XDocument test_doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                new XElement("Techaltum",
                        new XElement("student", new XAttribute("code", "101"),
                            new XElement("name", "Isha Malhotra"), 
                            new XElement("id", "1"), 
                            new XElement("course", "asp.net")),
                        new XElement("student", new XAttribute("code", "102"),
                             new XElement("name", "Avi Malhotra"), 
                             new XElement("id", "2"), 
                             new XElement("course", "web Desiging")),
                        new XElement("student", new XAttribute("code", "103"),
                             new XElement("name", "Neha"), 
                             new XElement("id", "3"), 
                             new XElement("course", "Java"))
             )
             );
//storage of file
string path = Server.MapPath("/Resources/abc.xml");
test_doc.Save(path);
```

Here is the path:

```
C:\\Developpements\\Blitz.SquareMax\\Blitz.SquareMax\\Resources\\abc.xml
```

This path exists in my machine.

This actually write this in my `abc.xml` but I still have the same exception :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Techaltum>
  <student code="101">
    <name />
  </student>
</Techaltum>
```

I just found it comes from the creation of XElement :
When I try to create a new XElement with a value like this `new XElement("name", "Isha Malhotra")` the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` appear
but if I remove the value `new XElement("name")` it's working.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please post the value of `path`. Have you verified that the path actually exists in your machine?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code on the debugger? It doesn't look like this is where it breaks. I think the exception is being thrown somewhere else.

Comment: I just found from where it comes but i still don't understand: the exception append when i try to set a value in XElement like this ```new XElement("id", "2")``` so if I write it like this ```new XElement("id")``` It works @JuanR

Comment: I think it's best you post the entire exception stack so we can help you. As you can see, the issue may not be where you think it is.

Comment: By the way, that is, IMHO, a horrific (and very difficult to debug as you have discovered) way of creating a document. I would recommend breaking that huge chunk into separate statements.

Comment: Just tried your code and it works fine (as ugly as it may be). Your issue is not the code. You must have an antivirus or something messing with the file or maybe you have the file open on an editor.

Comment: Yeah, I have a new message error : ```impossible to load file or assembly System.core``` I'm currently looking at it and for the moment I have found any working solution. I tried to add System.Core package with nuget but it seem's it's on user side so i'm currently trying to resolve this.

Comment: ```System.Core``` is called by ```System.Xml.Linq```